# What CLR is needed for C# 6?

Tags: c#-6.0

The title says it all: what CLR version is / will be needed to run C# 6 programs? The CLR version is interesting to find out the system requirements and supported operating systems.

I googled [[1]](https://www.google.de/search?q=clr+6+.net) [[2]](https://www.google.de/search?q=c%23+6+clr) and had a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but could not find the information.

Comment: What's been talked about so far is just syntax sugar, it doesn't require any new CLR features.  Using CLR v4.0.30319 should work just fine.  CLR versioning was never driven by compiler changes anyway.  The sane thing to do of course is just wait until it is actually released, then you *know*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0

Comment: If you are here to find out how to get the C# 6 language features, then I think @Pankaj answer is best.  It explains why this isn't actually a CLR question and what you need if you are using Visual Studio as your IDE.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C # 6 language enhancements  is compatible to .net framework starting from 2.0 to 4.6. It does not require any higher version of .net framework but need higher version of Visual studio such as VS 2015. C# 6 is also available to VS 2013 with addon https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Answer (score 9):

It is version 4 of CLR that is used. If you test [`Environment.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx) in [Visual Studio "14" CTPs](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-14-ctp-vs.aspx) you will get:

> 4.0.30319.35317

With code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
```

[image]

Also if you look at [Common Language Runtime (CLR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4) on MSDN you will find:

```
.Net Framework Version                     CLR Version
4.5 (including 4.5.1 and 4.5.2)            4
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to have C# 6 you need:

- VS 2013
- Download C# 6 from [Codeplex -Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/)

VS 2013 runs on .`NET 4.5.1` so I guess the answer to your Question is `4.5.1`

Comment: It is not `4.5.1`, .Net framework version is different from CLR version.