# C# 6.0, .NET 4.51 and VS2015 - Why does string interpolation work?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

After reading the following:

- [CLR Needed for C# 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605210/what-clr-is-needed-for-c-sharp-6)
- [Does C# 6.0 work for .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0)

it seemed to me that aside from [String Interpolation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) any project I compiled in VS2015 against .NET 4.51 could use the new C# language features.

However I tried the following code on my dev machine using VS2015 targeting 4.51:

```
string varOne = "aaa";

string varTwo = $"{varOne}";

if (varTwo == "aaa")
{

}
```

and not only did I not receive a compiler error, it worked as **varTwo**  contained **aaa** as expected.

Can someone explain why this is the case as I would not have expected this to work? I am guessing I am missing what FormattableString really means. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Perhaps it is smart enough to translate the string to a `String.Format` call?

Comment: `FormattableString` was introduced in .NET 4.5.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek So are you saying i3arnon's comment to Rubenisme is wrong in "Does C# 6.0...."?

Comment: It probably would work even with 1.0 if compiler could target it (can't due to other features like async) - `String.Format` was there forever (which is what interpolation is compiled into to my understanding)

Comment: @TheEdge please explain why you "would not have expected this to work" - it seem that information in posts you've linked to should be enough - so not clear what part you trying to clarify.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am targeting 4.5 and according to what I have read and what has been posted here "FormattableString is a new type introduced in .NET 4.6". So is my example only exploiting "string interpolation"? If so what example would exploit string interpolation **with** FormattableString?

Comment: @TheEdge `IFormattable s = $"{i}";` as shown in the post you've linked?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So if IFormattable was added in 4.6 and I am targeting **4.5** why does my code compile / work?

Comment: Because your code does not use `IFormattable`. What makes you think that you *do use* `IFormattable` in your sample code?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Can you give me a succinct example that does use IFormattable?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek `FormattableString` was **not** introduced in .Net 4.5. It was introduced in .Net 4.6.

Comment: String interpolation is a *language*, not a *framework* feature. It works as long as you select C# 6 as your language. In fact, this has been asked and answered a lot of tiimes already

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, string interpolation works in this case as all the new compiler does is convert the expression into an "equivalent string.Format call" at compile time.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx

> String interpolation is transformed at compile time to invoke an equivalent string.Format call. This leaves in place support for localization as before (though still with traditional format strings) and doesn’t introduce any post compile injection of code via strings.

The `FormattableString` is a new class allows you to inspect the string interpolation before rendering so you can check the values and protect against injection attacks.

```
// this does not require .NET 4.6
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string s = $"Hour is {now.Hour}";
Console.WriteLine(s);

//Output: Hour is 13

// this requires >= .NET 4.6
FormattableString fs = $"Hour is {now.Hour}";
Console.WriteLine(fs.Format);
Console.WriteLine(fs.GetArgument(0));

//Output: Hour is {0}
//13
```

Comment: Not sure how this answer is different/better than the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33249478/477420) (or how it addresses not-yet-identified concern of OP).

Comment: Added explanation of FormattableString class and examples.

Comment: @codersl Syntax error now.Hour --> DateTime.Now.Hour

Comment: I just tried this in VS2015 in a new console project and it works fine. I had to target framework .NET 4.6 though as it doesn't work with 4.5.x (which according to MSDN is the minimum required).

Comment: @codersl Sorry missed your local variable declaration of "now"

Answer (score 8):

> Can someone explain why this is the case as I would not have expected this to work?

This works since you're compiling with the new Roslyn compiler which ships with VS2015, and knows how to parse the string interpolation syntactic sugar (it simply calls the proper overload of `string.Format`). If you'd try to take advantage of .NET Framework 4.6 classes that work nicely with string interpolation, such as [`FormattableString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx), you'd run into a compile time error (unless you [*add them yourself*](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/02/24/customizing-string-interpolation-in-c-6/). See bottom part of the post).

> I am guessing I am missing what FormattableString really means.

`FormattableString` is a new type introduced in .NET 4.6, which allows you to use the new string interpolation feature with a custom `IFormatProvider` of your choice. Since this can't be done directly on the interpolated string, you can take advantage of `FormattableString.ToString(IFormatProvider)` which can be passed any custom format.

Comment: @downvoter So enlighten with a reason for the downvote.

Comment: It wasn't me, but [`FormattableString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring(v=vs.110).aspx) is in .Net 4.5

Comment: @DavidG not according to the docs: *.NET Framework
**Available since 4.6***

Comment: I felt it was relevant to the discussion between you and DavidG.

Comment: Downvote (not mine) likely due to the fact that information you've provided  is already covered in post OP linked to... But there is something OP does not understand - not really clear what so.

Comment: @Alexi But apparently OP doesn't quite understand the accepted answer. Since when is an attempt to answer a legitimate reason for a downvote?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov since beginning of time :) "not useful" - is subjective measure, but I can see how one can consider your post that way. (flagging NAA would be inappropriate indeed)

Comment: @Alexei I guess. Maybe I'm too naive to believe the fact that it would be nice of people to shed some light on what's wrong with an answer so one can improve it, instead of "drive-by downvoting" it. Bit, to each his own..

Comment: I have 4.5.1 targeted on my Dev box and string interpolation works fine.  I release the code and my Jenkins engineer is complaining that the deployment glitches on that box.  Is that because Jenkins doesn't use the newer compiler?  Should I switch back to composite formatting or can I get Jenkins to upgrade?