# how to use => operator in C# as return value for get accessor

Tags: c#, linq, class, lambda

I saw a source code of C# that it was using this syntax for get accessor in a class

```
public int _f;
public int f
{
    get => _f;
}
```

instead of

```
public int _f;
public int f
{
    get {return _f;}
}
```

and i was wondering do c# have => operator for simplifying

```
{return x;}
```

to

```
 => x;
```

if yes what is pre requisties of that? which c# version and which namespaces should be used?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new feature of C# 6.0. You can simply write:

```
public int f => _f;
```

instead of

```
public int f
{
    get { return _f; }
}
```

Remember that this is possible only if the property is readonly (it has only get accessor). Of course instead of `_f` you can write an expression returning proper type.

Comment: i checked the documentations and you were right, but problem is i cant compile that piece of code in any way!
now i'm installed visual studio 2015 update 3, my project is targeted for .net 4.6 but when i compile that class it fall error on get => ... part
it is telling that i hase error

in here cleared out all requirements for C# 6 but no success
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605210/what-clr-is-needed-for-c-sharp-6

Comment: Well, I don't know what is actually your problem. I can compile this piece of code without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can do it just if the property is read only, avoiding brackets:

```
public int MyProperty => 6;
```

And this has been introduced by the version 6 of the language, so up to **C# 5** this won't work either.

For setters as well it will be one of the new features of **C# 7**.

Comment: You can do this in C# 6 actually, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members.

Comment: @FredyTreboux only for getters as I wrote above.